# jess and backslashes when saving facts

Tags: java, jess

Until now i hardcoded the file paths in order to save facts or loading them into memory, but i have made modifications in the code when i ask for a file with a showSaveDialog() and get the path as well as name with getAbsolutePath(). The slice of code is as follows:

```
int retVal = fs.showSaveDialog(this);
          if (retVal == fs.APPROVE_OPTION){
        fn = fs.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
           . 
           .
           .
```

Now, the variable that receives the string is called fichero and is used on a jess sentence like this:

```
motor.eval("(save-facts "+fichero+")");
```

motor is the instance of the rete engine.
The problem is that jess uses the string but with simple backslashes '\', and it don't get saved correctly, because it gets all the string as the filename.
I have used the Jess console and noticed that the same string but with double backslashes on it '\' saves it correctly into the specified path. how can i replace the single slash with the double on the String fichero? I tried with fichero.replaceAll() method, using two strings as arguments, one with the single slash and the other with the double slash, but seems that java don't get it. The arguments described are declared as String var1 = "\" and String var2 = "\\". Using a println i observed that each one has a single and double backslash respectively, but did'nt seem to work when applied to the replaceAll() method.
Anyone can help?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The first string in replaceAll is a pattern. In a pattern, a single '\' must be escaped by prefixing another backslash. In the replacement string, '\' has a special meaning too.

```
s = s.replaceAll( "\\\\", "\\\\\\\\" );
```

Strange, but nevertheless...

Comment: Thanks for the help in the replaceAll method. It's strange indeed the way it has to be escaped the double backslash in order to get it recognized. Will try it and post my results later.

Answer (score 0):

If a usable Java API exists for a Jess feature, you should use it rather than building a command string and interpreting it; it's going to be simpler, easier, and more efficient. For the save-facts case, there is indeed such an API: the `jess.Rete` class has three overloads of `ppFacts()` which pretty-print the desired facts directly to a `Writer` you provide. See [here](http://www.jessrules.com/jess/docs/71/api/jess/Rete.html#ppFacts%28java.io.Writer%29) for Javadocs.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Will investigate the ppFacts() overloads and see if i can come with a solution.